# Custom reset password routes in laravel 5.0

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing, password-recovery, reset-password

I want to make some custom routes for **password resets**, here's what i've done so far:

First, i created my own routes

```
    Route::controllers([
            'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
            'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
        ]);

    Route::get('/olvide-mi-contrasena', [
        'as' => 'clubOlvide',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail'
    ]);

    Route::post('/olvide-mi-contrasena', [
        'as' => 'clubPostOlvide',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail'
    ]);

    Route::get('/restablecer-contrasena/{token}', [
        'as' => 'clubRestablecer',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset'
    ]);

    Route::post('/restablecer-contrasena/{token}', [
        'as' => 'clubPostRestablecer',
        'uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset'
    ]);
```

Second, i overrided  the ResetsPasswords trait at PasswordController

```
        private $redirectTo = '/ingresar';
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return view('Club.auth.password');
        }

        public function getReset($token = null)
        {
            if (is_null($token))
            {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException;
            }

            return view('Club.auth.reset')->with('token', $token);
        }
```

Third, change the action at the view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('clubPostRestablecer',['token' => $token]) }}">
```

Fourth, i edited the mail configuration

```
return [

    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => ['address' => 'soporte@domain.tld', 'name' => 'Support'],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'googlemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'googlePassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

And i tested it... It send the reset link, and the link works, it resets the password, but it's using the default route, i want it to send the custom route, here's what i'm saying:

Email received (i'll replace the real token with word token in the link to make the post more readable):

> Click here to reset your password:
>
> http://domain.tld/password/reset/token

What i want it to be:

> Click here to reset your password:
>
> http://domain.tld/restablecer-contrasena/token

If i copy the token sent to `password/reset/token` and paste it `restablecer-contrasena/token` it works, so i would like to know how to change the link sent to the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!, The password reset email uses a template, configured in **config/auth.php** See:

> When a user submits a request to reset their password, they will
>   receive an e-mail with a link that points to the getReset method
>   (typically routed at /password/reset) of the PasswordController. You
>   will need to create a view for this e-mail at
>   resources/views/emails/password.blade.php. The view will receive the
>   $token variable which contains the password reset token to match the
>   user to the password reset request. Here is an example e-mail view to
>   get you started:

```
<!-- resources/views/emails/password.blade.php -->

Click here to reset your password: {{ route('clubPostRestablecer',['token' => $token]) }}
```